# How to get json file from sql db

Tags: python, flask, fullcalendar, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created a flask app. To store the data I have used sqlalchemy to create a db file.
My aim is to create an event calendar. I have decided to use FullCalendar.io .  But the issue is that to feed the data  it needs json file. Can anyone help me out

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
    from flask.wrappers import Request
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from datetime import datetime
    
    from sqlalchemy.orm import query
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///caldb.db'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    
    class CalData(db.Model):
        date = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
        title = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
        desc = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
        time = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
        link = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    
        def __repr__(self) -> str:
            return f"{self.title} - {self.time}"
        @app.route('/cal2')
        def cal2():
            cd = CalData.query.all()
            return render_template("cal2.html", data=cd)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with FullCalendar.io, but let's assume that you need a list of objects, each representing a single calendar event, in the format you've described in the ORM model. Then, you only need to put all the data from the instances you get from your query into `dict`s, and then send it out with [`jsonify`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify):

```py
from flask import jsonify

...
...
...

@app.route('/cal2')
def cal2():
  result = []
  calendar_entries = CalData.query.all()
  for entry in calendar_entries:
    obj = dict()
    obj['date'] = entry.date
    obj['title'] = entry.title
    ...
    result.append(obj)
  return jsonify(result)
```